# Azure Queue Storage message not getting saved in the right queue On Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

```
const azure = require('azure-storage');
const queueService = azure.createQueueService("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    context.log('Request Headers = ' + JSON.stringify(req.headers));

    queueName = 'azurequeue';

    if ((req.query.parameter && req.query.func) || (req.body && req.body.parameter && req.body.func)) {

        var send = new Object();

        var message = 'Hello world!' 

        queueService.createQueueIfNotExists(queueName,function(err, result, response) {
            if (err) {
                context.log('here')
                context.error(err);
              return;
            }

            if (result.created) {
                context.log(`[Queue - Sender] Queue ${queueName} did not exist, created it`);
            }

            queueService.createMessage(queueName, message , (err, result, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    context.error(`[Queue - Sender] An error occurred: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
                }

                context.log(`[Queue - Sender] Sent: ${JSON.stringify(message)}`);
            });

          });

        send.ans = 'Hello world!'; 

        context.res = {
            body: send
        };

    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }
};
```

i am writing an azure Function with httpTrigger. When triggered is should save to a queue name 'azurequeue' hosted in azure storage emulator.

error i am getting [image: Error]

[image: Storage]

Is there something i am  doing wrong? how to solve this. why is this happening?

Comment: Instead of sharing screenshot of code, please share the actual code in question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you mix HttpTrigger and QueueTrigger together.

If you want to use your own logic above to write message to queue, make sure your `function.json` is like below.

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

If [outputbinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#output---javascript-example) feature provided by Azure function is preferred, let's use code below. No need to worry that `azurequeue` doesn't exist, output binding internally uses createQueueIfNotExists.

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    context.log('Request Headers = ' + JSON.stringify(req.headers));

    if ((req.query.parameter && req.query.func) || (req.body && req.body.parameter && req.body.func)) {

        var message = 'Hello world!' 
        var send = {'ans' : message};

        return {
            res: {
                body: send
            },
            queueOutput: message
        };
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
        return;
    }
};
```

And don't forget to add queue output in `function.json`.

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "queue",
      "direction": "out",
      "name":"queueOutput" ,
      "queueName": "azurequeue",
      "connection":"AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

To avoid other obstacle in the future, have a look at [Azure Function guidance of javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node).